# How to get list of events via GRAPH API with LimitedDetails permissions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I try to get a list of events via [List calendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

It works as expected when users have `Reviewer` permissions in the exchange server, but as soon as they have only `LimitedDetails` - I have an error "access denied".

I assume that the problem is that with `LimitedDetails` I can only get subjects (without event body).

How can I request the list of events (I need Subject, ICallId and IsAllDayEvent properties) in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limited Details is a FreeBusy permission so it should work in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http as this queries the users freebusy time but it won't work when trying to query the calendar which requires reviewer or greater.

Comment: Thanks Glen. Sounds reasonable. Is there any place where it is written explicitly? Or it is just your logical assumption?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxfolderpermission lists out all the permissions and what they apply to, Exchange DACL's are a bit a different and the concept or querying the availability data is also a bit different